# Get wrapped lines of QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt

Is there any way to get each line as displayed in a QTextEdit?

I have some unformatted text which is displayed in a QTextEdit like this:

```
QString someText = "bla bla bla bla  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla";
QTextEdit* texEdit = new QTextEdit();
textEdit->setLineWrapMode(QTextEdit::FixedColumnWidth);
texEdit->setLineWrapColumnOrWidth(38);
texEdit->setWordWrapMode(QTextOption::WordWrap);
texEdit->setText(someText);
```

Which displays "someText" as 2 lines in textEdit

```
bla bla bla bla  bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla
```

Now I want to get each line as displayed in my QTextEdit.
However I have yet failed to achieve this.

At first I naively tried

```
textEdit->toPlainText().split("\n")
```

which unfortunately does not give me the wrapped lines, since wrapping does not insert line breaks.

So i thought maybe QTextDocument is the way to go, which turned out a to be dead end too.

```
QTextDocument* doc = textEdit->document();

qDebug() << "document linecount: " << doc->lineCount();
qDebug() << "block count:" << doc->blockCount();
qDebug() << "lines in block: " << doc->findBlock(1).lineCount();
```

Each of these return 1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to get each line of the wrapped text (as it displayed inside the QTextEdit) as a separate QString, right?

[QTextDocument](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html) from QTextEdit control stores its text by paragraphs (represented by [QTextBlock](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QTextBlock.html)), each paragraph laid out as a set of text lines ([QTextLine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QTextLine.html)). You just need to extract those lines of text from there. Here's my code sample.

```
QStringList splitByLines(const QTextDocument *doc)
{
  if(!doc)
    return QStringList();
  QStringList ret;
  QTextBlock tb = doc->begin();
  while(tb.isValid())
  {
    QString blockText = tb.text();
    Q_ASSERT(tb.layout());
    if(!tb.layout())
      continue;
    for(int i = 0; i != tb.layout()->lineCount(); ++i)
    {
      QTextLine line = tb.layout()->lineAt(i);
      ret.append(blockText.mid(line.textStart(), line.textLength()));
    }
    tb = tb.next();
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Now you can simply call splitByLines(textEdit->document()) to get what you want. And please note that you have to re-extract the lines when document layout (see [documentLayoutChanged()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#documentLayoutChanged)) or contents (see [contentsChanged()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#contentsChanged)) change.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. works like a charm. I thought I was getting mad, since every lineCount I could find returned 1. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help :) Actually, I was looking for a question to raise my reputation to be able to upvote an answer I liked. So thanks for the question ;)